# Хранение адресов из Google Place API

Tags: google-places-api

Хочу использовать в своем приложении адреса из Google Place API. Так как не возможно получить всю базу, я хотел отправлять запросы с максимальным радиусом в каждом населенном пункте и добавлять в свою базу данных название, тип и координаты (либо адрес).

Можно ли хранить такие данные на постоянной основе. Поискав в интернете, некоторые пишут, что можно хранить только id на постоянной основе, некоторые пишут, что можно хранить в течении 30 дней.

Хотелось бы получить конкретные ответы что можно хранить (и на какой срок), а что нельзя?

Возможно возникнут у некоторых вопросы, почему нельзя отправлять запрос и получить места. 
Ответ: эти данные будут использоваться для экономической игры, поэтому будет происходить постоянная манипуляция этими данными в базе данных.

Возможно вы знаете другую базу зданий, но только чтобы она была бесплатной

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что лучше обратиться к документации Google:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id

> Идентификаторы места освобождаются от ограничений кэширования,
>   указанных в разделе 3.2.4 (a) Условий использования платформы Google
>   Maps. Поэтому вы можете хранить значения идентификатора места для
>   последующего использования.

Но

> Идентификатор места может устареть, если бизнес закрывается или
>   перемещается в новое место.
>   ...
>   старый идентификатор возвращает NOT_FOUNDответ.

Так что можете смело хранить id.
Можете хранить так же и сами данные каждого места.
Однако, придётся делать периодическое обновление информации. Данные ведь, могут и поменяться.

Comment: Ну это я тоже читал, что идентификатор можно хранить, но нужно также хранить географические координаты и адрес. Вот про них ни слова. Если хранить только идентификатор в базе данных, то придется каждый раз отправлять идентификатор в сервис с backend, а там имеется ограничение на определенное количество запросов в месяц

Comment: @danilshik погодите, а почему вы думаете что должны быть рекомендации  по хранению полученных данных на вашей стороне? Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Вопрос был про хранение данных на постоянной основе. К данным относится не только идентификатор места но и другие данные. Вот с ними и вызывается неопределеннось. Просто будет обидно после разработки выложить приложения и Google Play тебе откажет. Может кто-то использовал этот сервис, либо  кого то уже есть готовые приложения с ним